# Filter pivottable in Excel 2003

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

How do I filter a pivot table in Excel 2003 using VBA?

In Excel 2007 I can run this macro but PivotFilters are not implemented in XL 2003.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Date").PivotFilters.Add _
        Type:=xlSpecificDate, Value1:="26/01/2012"
```

Update:
I get an error "Run-time error '1004". Unable to set the Visible property of the PivotItem class.

Sub Filter()
    Dim PvtItem As PivotItem
    Dim ws As Worksheet

```
Set ws = Sheets("pivot")

'~~> Show All
For Each PvtItem In ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Date").PivotItems
    PvtItem.Visible = True
Next

'~~> Show Only the relevant
For Each PvtItem In ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Date").PivotItems
    If PvtItem.Value <> "26/01/2012" Then PvtItem.Visible = False  '<-- error here
Next
```

End Sub

http://wikisend.com/download/426518/pivot.xls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To filter a PivotField in VBA 2003, you have to set/unset the .Visible Property. here is an example

```
Option Explicit

Sub Filter()
    Dim PvtItem As PivotItem
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    On Error GoTo Whoa1

    Set ws = Sheets("pivot")

    '~~> Show All
    For Each PvtItem In ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Date").PivotItems
        PvtItem.Visible = True
    Next

    On Error GoTo Whoa2 '<~~ If no match found in Pivot

    '~~> Show Only the relevant
    For Each PvtItem In ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Date").PivotItems
        If Format(PvtItem.Value, "DD/MM/YYYY") <> Format(Range("today"), "DD/MM/YYYY") Then
            PvtItem.Visible = False
        End If
    Next

    Exit Sub
Whoa1:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Exit Sub
Whoa2:
    '~~> Show All
    For Each PvtItem In ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Date").PivotItems
        PvtItem.Visible = True
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I get an error: "Unable to Set Visible Property PivotItem class"
It seems to be a known bug, I am using a Microsoft support engineer. I will let you know what I have a solution.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/isvvba/thread/01fca3d7-944e-4fb6-bf9b-0e7892b0234c

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand? What is the "bug" that yo are referring to?

Comment: I tried to set the sort order to manual and the orientation as surgested but non helps

Comment: But I didn't suggest anything to do with sort order and orientation :) Can you explain in detail what the problem is?

Comment: I will setup a small sample project that shows the problem. Where can I share the sheet with you?

Comment: You can upload the file in wikisend.com and share the link here?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7120/discussion-between-user800454-and-siddharth-rout)