# Filter Pivot in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, excel-2003

I have a problem with this filter if I set the regional language format to to English (United Kingdom), it works well if I use English (Unites States).
My problem is that the filter does not make the selection of May 30 invisible, it fails in that call and goto the error section.

http://wikisend.com/download/138750/Pivottable.xls

is this a known bug? http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;114822&Product=xlw

It filters dates simular to post [Filter pivottable in Excel 2003](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034499/filter-pivottable-in-excel-2003)

```
Sub Filter()
    Dim PvtItem As PivotItem
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    On Error GoTo Whoa1

    Set ws = Sheets("pivot")

    '~~> Show All
    For Each PvtItem In ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Date").PivotItems
        PvtItem.Visible = True
    Next

    On Error GoTo Whoa2 '<~~ If no match found in Pivot

    '~~> Show Only the relevant
    For Each PvtItem In ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Date").PivotItems
        If Format(PvtItem.Value, "DD/MM/YYYY") <> Format(Range("today"), "DD/MM/YYYY") Then
            PvtItem.Visible = False
        End If
    Next

    Exit Sub
Whoa1:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Exit Sub
Whoa2:
    '~~> Show All
    For Each PvtItem In ws.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Date").PivotItems
        PvtItem.Visible = True
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry was unclear added a better description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TRIED AND TESTED IN EXCEL 2003 (With UK Settings)**

Right click on the Date Field as shown in the snapshot and click on `Field Settings` and then click on `Number`. Set the Date format as shown. Now try the same code.

[image]